# Change link color when main div is hover

Tags: html, css, hover

my issue is that, when I hover over my div, it doesn't change the links color to what I want it to be. It just stays its default black color as it is defined.  But when I hover on link directly in div then link change color.

How can I make it so that when I hover over main div, it changes the color of the link inside in div?

Link to my website: https://www.temporary-url.com/CF16F6
tail: more news

I have code like below:

```
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3):hover a
{
     color: #CB701A;  
}

/* unvisited link */

div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(3) > a:link
{
  color: #333333;
}

/* visited link */
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(3) > a:visited
{
  color: #CB701A;
}

/* selected link */
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(3) > a:active 
{
  color: #333333;
}

/* mouse over link */
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(3) > a:hover
{
  color: #CB701A;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to place the `:hover` attribute on the div rather than the `a` tag

```
/* mouse over link */
div.zsm_block_news > div.zsm_block_content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(3):hover > a
{
  color: #CB701A;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately is not working, still I need to hover `a` tag section

Comment: sorry Majan but which a tag on your website do you want to change on hover as the temporary link there is quite a few links could you give me and image

Comment: main page 2nd row od tailf with information "more news"

Comment: I cant find the text "more news" on your page can you give me the text on your webpage you want to change?